# Laravel página en blanco

Tags: php, laravel, php7, composer, laravel-6

Tengo un pequeño proyecto con laravel en local, hoy he decidido subirlo a un servidor remoto pero solo se ve el index, al intentar entrar a cualquier ruta se quedan las páginas en blanco. 
He subido el proyecto al servidor mediante git, luego he hecho un `composer install` y he creado el archivo `.env` con los datos de mi base de datos y servidor. He comprobado que el archivo de rutas esta igual que en local y lo esta.
He creado la siguiente ruta en `routes/web.php`

> Route::get('/asd', function() {
>       echo "hola"; });

pero sigue sin mostrar nada, solo funciona el index de midominio.es/public

Alguna idea de porque puede ser?

PD: Uso laravel 6

EDIT:
Adjunto captura del .htaccess que esta en el mismo nivel que public:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo del .htaccess que hay dentro de public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Prueba a ejcutar este comando en la raiz del proyecto: `composer dump-autoload` y tambien debes tener una key del proyecto : `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Usaste un Virtual Host o Alias Directory ?, creo que te faltan algunas configuraciones en esos archivos o en el `.httacces` de tu proyecto

Comment: Acabo de hacer el `composer dump-autoload` y `php artisan key:generate` pero sigue pasando lo mismo, en el desarrollo en local no use virtualhost, iba desarrolando y probando con `php artisan serve`